# Javascript error - SXBB[id].resize is not a function

Tags: javascript

[My forum](http://digital-diy.com/forum/) (based on phpbb3) has a Javascript error that I'd like to resolve. In FF and IE the following error occurs:

```
Error: SXBB[id].resize is not a function
Source File: http://digital-diy.com/forum/classes/scripts/select_expand_bbcodes.js
Line: 197
```

The mod that uses this script is called "Syntax Highlighter 1.0.15". The developer is not sure why the error occurs, hopefully someone at stackoverflow can lend a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Track down the `SXBB` object or array and view the `id` variable.

Make sure that property (what `id` refers to) is set on that object (`SXBB`).

My guess is it isn't, and it's `undefined`, and `undefined` has no `resize()` method.

Comment: Cheers - I am more of a functional/end user developer, and am not very familiar with Javascript.

Comment: @Graham Hopefully those steps above help you to track down the problem. For a *quick and dirty* fix, try wrapping the call to `resize()` with `if (SXBB[id] !== undefined) { ... }`.

Comment: I have no idea how to view the id variable and check if the property is set on the variable - what steps should I take to do that?

Comment: Sorry alex, we commented at the same time - I will try your quick fix first

Comment: The error is removed, although the resize function seems to no longer work (at all). [Here's a demo of the mod](http://digital-diy.com/forum/site-annoucements/site-updates-t1488.html#p9089), there should be an "Expand" link on the right of "Select" [Here's a demo of the mod](http://digital-diy.com/forum/site-annoucements/site-updates-t1488.html#p9089)

Comment: @Graham: If you're an end-user, perhaps instead the _developer_ of the broken mod should be asking here?

Comment: I totally agree - I have discussed the issue with the developer, although we couldn't find a fix..

Comment: @Tomalak Yep, I'd be shocked if the developer sent an end user here to ask a question.

Comment: @Alex that is not what has happened! I am exploring the issue with other people, nothing more :) Who knows - a solution might jump out at someone

Comment: @Alex - my first attempt at the for loop I had wrapped the code incorectly. I've since changed it and the expand link now displays. That said, so too does the JS error.

Sorry for the confusion at first - does this new info help in anyway? [see line 199 of this file](http://digital-diy.com/forum/classes/scripts/select_expand_bbcodes.js)

Comment: Any other takers on this issue?